# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certs.check' Python Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a folder strcture as

```
-->Certs (Folder)
   --> check.crt
--->client.py




  class Client:
        def get_parameters(self):
            client = pymongo.MongoClient(
                "mongodb://" + constants.USER_NAME + ":" + constants.PWD + constants.server +certs.check )
             print("Done")
   c=Client()
   c.get_parameters()
```

I am getting an error 'certs.check'

I have tried

```
from certs import *
import certs.check
```

Please tell me how to import this file

Comment: The `import` statement is for python files exclusively. To open a file and read from it, use the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For PY files:

Try the following steps:

1. In the `certs` folder, add an empty file named `__init__.py`, and make the `__init__.py` file empty.
2. Import with the following code:

   ```
   from certs import check
   ```

### For IO files (not PY files):

Try using `open`:

```
with open('certs/check.crt') as f:
    # do something with `f`.
```

## For MongoDB:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://" + constants.USER_NAME + ":" + constants.PWD + constants.server + 'certs/check.crt')
```

Comment: dont want to open a file want to  add as a string something like this
 client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://" + constants.USER_NAME + ":" + constants.PWD + constants.server +certs.check )

Comment: @user15780176 Check my edit, please accept and upvote if it works